# Angularfire2- how to compare two JSON arrays length containing nested Objects stored as Documents in firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

[image: this is my firestore structure both documents contain the same keys and different values]

I want to display a document that has the most number of keys. Here is my Code

```
this.todoCollectionRef = this.afs.collection<any>("localization");
this.todo$ = this.todoCollectionRef.valueChanges();
 this.todo$.subscribe(res =>{

})
this.todo$.subscribe((res) => {
  res.forEach((element) => {
    this.data_tree.push(element);
  }); 
  // console.log(element , "tree data");
  TREE_DATA = JSON.stringify(this.data_tree);
});
```

I want some kind of function that'll check which document has more keys and that document will be assigned to **TREE_DATA**

[image: this is what data_tree returns I want to compare 0 and 1 position of the array which can be more so it'll be dynamic]

this is what data_tree returns I want to compare 0 and 1 position of the array which has more keys and there can be more documents so I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: when you say "document that has the most number of keys", what is the depth? Should all the children and their subsequent children needs to be counted or only the first set of childrens?

Comment: i am talking about total lenght of that JSON with its nested childs